# Why does the aggregate functions in GEE the only one using snake case?

Tags: google-earth-engine

While reading the documentation I realized that all the aggregate methods from `FeatureCollection` are using snake_case instead of the camelCase used for all the other methods.
Is there a specific reason or is it a legacy thing like `int` and `toInt` ?

e.g. `aggregate_array`